# Keeping only last N records of a user based on timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this for recent book searches by users. I have to maintain only the last 3 records for a user. Say in the below table we have 3 entries for user 123, if a new entry like `123, DEF, 2020-11-28 21:08:39` comes in, I should insert this one and remove the last one based on timestamp i.e 2nd entry from the table. What's the best way to achieve this? Can this be done in one DB call? Or do I need to insert first, check if the count for a user is greater than 3, and then delete the oldest one?

```
+------------+-------------+---------------------+
| User Id    | Book Name   | Last Searched       |
+------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 123        | ABC         | 2020-10-09 23:10:36 |
| 123        | XYZ         | 2020-10-08 21:08:39 |
| 123        | PRO         | 2020-11-27 02:32:26 |
| 456        | XYZ         | 2020-09-11 11:41:19 |
| 456        | PRO         | 2020-10-03 22:09:42 |
+------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Yes, This can be implemented in a DB call with a stored procedure which can delete the oldest row and insert the new row.

Comment: Assuming this is a real process rather than a homework assignment, the response time on the user's search would be critical.  As a result, it wouldn't make sense to do this check at the time you're doing the search.  It would make much more sense to just blindly insert a new row and then have a separate process (potentially a simple polling job) that runs every day/ hour/ whatever to tidy up the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could try is to create an `AFTER STATEMENT` trigger and just run the following query inside of it:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ai_some_table_old
AFTER INSERT ON some_table
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM some_table st
  WHERE st.rowid IN (SELECT s.row_id
                     FROM (SELECT ROWID AS ROW_ID, 
                                  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY s.user_id ORDER BY s.last_searched DESC) AS REC_RANK
                           FROM some_table s) s
                     WHERE s.rec_rank > 3);
END;
/
```

Here is a DB Fiddle showing you the whole process ([Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=509376cf1efc13d779085980059800c2))

If you really wanted to get tricky...or if the performance of the `DELETE` is bad, you could create a `COMPOUND TRIGGER` which limits the USER_ID column based on records which were touched as part of the statement.

Comment: All the table aliases in your query are redundant.

Comment: @MT0 I realize that, but I just always put them in.  Helps me keep things straight when it gets complicated.

Comment: Table aliases make things much clearer especially when the same table is used in the filtering subquery

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything in a single `merge` statement.

With this data for testing:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';

create table tbl (user_id, book_name, last_searched) as
  select 123, 'ABC', to_date('2020-10-09 23:10:36') from dual union all
  select 123, 'XYZ', to_date('2020-10-08 21:08:39') from dual union all
  select 123, 'PRO', to_date('2020-11-27 02:32:26') from dual union all
  select 456, 'XYZ', to_date('2020-09-11 11:41:19') from dual union all
  select 456, 'PRO', to_date('2020-10-03 22:09:42') from dual
;
```

Here is the `merge` statement. The new data is in the `with` clause in the `using(...)` section; I hard-coded values there, but you can pass data from bind variables, or a temp table for new rows, etc. (you will need to make some small changes). The "new" dates don't actually have to be newer than the existing dates (in the table); the query will just keep the three most recent ones per user id, regardless of where they come from. It can also clean up a table where you currently have more than three rows per user id, and it also handles users that weren't in the table already.

```
merge into tbl
  using(
    with
      new_data (user_id, book_name, last_searched) as (
        select 123, 'DEF', to_date('2020-11-28 21:08:39') from dual union all
        select 888, 'AAA', to_date('2020-10-03 15:00:00') from dual
        )
    , prep (rid, user_id, book_name, last_searched) as (
        select  t.rowid, t.user_id, t.book_name, t.last_searched
          from  tbl t left join new_data n on t.user_id = n.user_id
        union all
        select  null, user_id, book_name, last_searched
          from new_data 
        )
    select rid, user_id, book_name, last_searched,
           row_number() over (partition by user_id
                                  order by last_searched desc) as rn
    from   prep
  ) src
  on (src.rid = tbl.rowid)
when matched 
  then update set tbl.user_id = src.user_id
  delete where rn > 3
when not matched 
  then insert values (src.user_id, src.book_name, src.last_searched)
    where rn <= 3
;
```